# maven-gpg-plugin failing with "Inappropriate ioctl for device" when running under Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, maven-gpg-plugin

When Jenkins triggers `maven-gpg-plugin` in a remote Linux shell it fails with `gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device`. This used to work until recently. I don't know what changed.

I found a lot of online references suggesting `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` but this doesn't work for ssh connections as `tty` is `null`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found an excellent explanation over at https://myshittycode.com/2017/08/07/maven-gpg-plugin-prevent-signing-prompt-or-gpg-signing-failed-no-such-file-or-directory-error/

I will re-post the gist of the post in case the page goes down:

> If you 1) initially had it working in the past, and 2) have tried all sorts of solutions from the web, and still couldn’t get it working, chances are you have unconsciously upgraded GPG version from 2.0 to 2.1.

Sounds about right...

> To fix this, GPG 2.1 requires **--pinentry-mode** to be set to **loopback** in order to pick up gpg.passphrase value defined in Maven settings.xml.
>
> So, update Maven GPG Plugin configuration in pom.xml to the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>sign-artifacts</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>sign</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <gpgArguments>
                    <arg>--pinentry-mode</arg>
                    <arg>loopback</arg>
                </gpgArguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I'm still getting `gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device` with this configuration. I'm using Maven 3.6.3 and GnuPG 2.2.12.

Comment: Also, apparently this feature is handled automatically in the (as of yet unreleased) maven-gpg-plugin version 3.0.0: https://github.com/apache/maven-gpg-plugin/commit/11aca384c4005747d797dcc4857280d0d578d05f/

Comment: I managed to get it working by moving the `<configuration>` section to directly under `<plugin>`

Comment: @Guss tried with maven-gpg-plugin 3.0.1 and this problem still persists.

Comment: @wlnirvana - did you try my solution with the `<configuration>` section?

Comment: This fixes it for gpg 2.1+, however, it breaks it for older versions, so if you have a mixed pool of machines, you may prefer to conditionally configure this setting in  `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` and leave your pom.xml files alone.

Comment: Is there an equivalent solution for Gradle? This fixed up my Maven builds, but I'm facing the same problem with the Gradle signing plugin.

Comment: @leros Not that I know of. I suggest opening a new question that references this answer.

Answer (score 2):

*To build on Gili's answer:*

Rather than modify every pom.xml to make Jenkins happy, you can add the following to `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` on Jenkins slaves with newer gpg:

```
pinentry-mode loopback
```

### Puppet

You can also automate this. I'm using puppet to create `gpg.conf` files with this entry if gpg version is 2.1 or higher:

##### Template

```rb
<% if scope.lookupvar("gpg_version").to_f >= 2.1 %>
pinentry-mode loopback
<% end %>
```

##### Fact

```rb
Facter.add("gpg_version") do
  setcode do

    result = ''
    begin
      first_line = `gpg --version`.split("\n")[0]
      match = first_line.match /.* ([0-9\.]*)$/
      result = match[1]
    rescue

    end
    result
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading to a newer maven-gpg-plugin version helped in my case. From 1.5 to 3.0.1.

Hopefully it will be at least a try for somebody

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0.1</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>sign-artifacts</id>
        <phase>verify</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>sign</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <gpgArguments>
        <argument>--pinentry-mode</argument>
        <argument>loopback</argument>
    </gpgArguments>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Isn't this already covered by the accepted answer? The code seems to be identical.

Comment: @Gili, in this answer the `<configuration>...</configuration>` part is after `<executions>...</executions>`, whereas in the accepted answer it was in `<executions><execution>` right after `</goals>`. Anyway, it didn't fix the issue for me.

Comment: @i01573 In the case of a single execution, both forms are equivalent. As far as I can tell, this answer doesn't add anything new to the discussion.

Comment: I stand corrected. This answer adds one thing to the discussion: upgrading the plugin version helps!